# Firefox button issue (every other broswer works)

Tags: php, android, firefox, browser

I've created a button which allows the user to download an .apk file which works for most browers except Firefox.

Why is the button not working in Firefox yet other links work fine!

```
<?php
    $server     = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $page       = $server . '/web/text';
    $appUrl     = $server . '/android/Application.apk';

    header("Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
    ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN"
   "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "<a href='http://$page'>This Works Fine</a>"; ?>.
<br />
<br />
<button type="button"><?php echo "<a href='http://$appUrl'>Download</a>"; ?></button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Firefox is far stricter than the other browsers:

Anchor should not be defined inside a button element, Chrome etc allow this however for Firefox the button should be in a form.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for, easy and compatible with every (normal) browser:

```
<button id="download-button" type="button">Download</button>

$('#download-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "www.yourdownloadurl.com";
});
```